# Unable to upload to Watson Analytics data with R

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I have the following code:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "X-IBM-Client-Id:YOUR_CLIENT_ID" -H "X-IBM-Client-Secret:YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type:text/csv" https://api.ibm.com/watsonanalytics/run/data/v1/datasets/ID_OF_DATA_SET/content -d "YOUR_DATA"
```

That code is the example they gave me in order to upload data, when I try to translate the to R it looks like this: 
I am using the following libraries: 
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(XML)
library(httr)
library(readr)

and the code looks like :

```
Upload_data<-PUT( url = "https://api.ibm.com/watsonanalytics/run/data/v1/datasets/DataID/content",
              add_headers('Content-Type' = 'text/csv'),
              add_headers('Accept'= 'application/json'),
              add_headers('X-IBM-Client-Secret' = Secret),
              add_headers('X-IBM-Client-Id' = Client),
              add_headers('Authorization: Bearer'=Auth, body= "Province,Population density,Area,Population,
                          Ontario,97,83858,8169929
                          Quebec,337,30510,11007020
                          Alberta,111,547030,63601002
                          Manitoba,233,357021,81799600
                          British Columbia,393,41526,16824400
                          Costa Rica, 1,10000, 1000000"))
```

Seems that it is not working, do you know some way to fix it?

Comment: does that first block of code run fine if you try from the command line?

Comment: I am using Gitbash and yes, it is working, the data set is uploaded into Watson Analytics, but when I try with R seems that  it is not working/

Comment: hmm, what about wrapping it with a `system()` call?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: `?system` should give you the details but basically its a way for R to send a command to your OS

Comment: Perfect, let me try it

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe that R is not yet supported through the Watson Analytics API Explorer, which is what your PUT request is using *"https://api.ibm.com/watsonanalytics/"*

The supported languages include Python, JavaScript, Java, C#, and PHP.